# refresh jquery mobile text inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been working with JQM for a couple of weeks and after studying various examples and reading the docs, I cannot seem to find a way to refresh text inputs in a success callback. Is this possible with v1.0b2. I can refresh(reset) other elements just not text inputs. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/f6Prp/6/

JS

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('.resetMe').val('');
    $("input[name='checkbox-1']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    $("input[name='radio-choice-1']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="resetMe" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" class="resetMe"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" />
                <label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" />
                <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="reset">Reset button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am dynamically creating some text inputs in my code (based on button clicks).  Because they are being created **after** the page is rendered, they were all showing the standard UI (instead of jquery mobile css look and feel.)  I found out that I have to "refresh" them after creating them (similar to how you refresh a button or other element.)

After creating the inputs, I add the line:

```
$('#myInputName').textinput();
```

to refresh

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a class to the text inputs and then set the values on those elements like so:

```
$(".my_class").val("");
```